# google analytics data API - Property ID

Tags: api, analytics

I am using google analytics data API. Making an API Call as listed here - https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/data/v1/quickstart-client-libraries.

My question is how do I enabled google analytics Data API for an already existing project. I need access to specific property ID.

any information is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You have to follow Step 1 (Enable the API) and Step 2 (Add service account to the Google Analytics 4 property) in your link. Then use your property ID called **Measurement ID** (i.e. G-XXXXXXXX) that you can find in Data Streams (selecting a Data Stream) in Google Analytics 4 Admin Panel.

Answer (score 0):

Following [google support link](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/9304153?authuser=1), you should first log into  analytics.google, then in admin page [image].

then click on GA4 setup Assistant like the photo [image]